# Webpack cannot parse JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am new to using webpack and react. I have found solutions to this kind problem, but they don't seem to apply to me in the sense that it was normally missing dependencies or incorrect formatting of the webpack config file.

My package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  }
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/app/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
    publicPath:"/app/"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
        {
            test:/.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: SRC_DIR +"/app",
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query:{
                presets:["es2015","react","stage-2","react-dom"]
            }
        }
    ]
  }
};
```

My index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Layout extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Work please</h1>
        );
    }
} 

render(<Layout/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Error message

```
  ERROR in ./src/app/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| class Layout extends React.Component {
|
| const app =   render(){
|               return(
|                       <h1>Work please</h1>
```

Comment: try changing your entry to ./index.js and change your test to /.(js|jsx)$/

Comment: I've tried changing my test to /.(js|jsx)$/, it doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration requires files containing jsx to end in the .jsx extension.

Change your test to /.(js|jsx)$/

Comment: I was just missing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your component looks to be a mix of a React Class Component (React.Component) and a Stateless Functional Component (SFC)

try changing this...

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    const app = render(){
        return(
            <h1>Work please</h1>
        );
    }
} 
document.getElementById('app');
render(<Layout>,app)
```

to either a Stateless Functional Component (SFC):

```
...
import { render } from 'react-dom';
...
const App = () => (
  <h1>Work please</h1>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

or a [React Class Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

```
...
import { render } from 'react-dom';
...
class Layout extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Work please</h1>
        );
    }
} 
;
render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

more on [Functional and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)

Comment: Aah yes, must have happened when I was still trying to figure out where the issue was and ended up mixing up various components. Sorry about that. It still doesn't seem to fix the issue though.

Comment: do you have `import { render } from 'react-dom';`?  Is the error message the same?